# How to append HTML in epplus worksheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I'm exporting my HTML report into excel using c#. I m writing all my HTML in response (`Response.Write()`) along with css and download excel and its working fine. Now I'm in a need to separate its HTML parts into separate sheets.

How can I do that? Is there a way I can do it via EPPlus?

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=EntryPlanningReport.xls");            
Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
Response.Write("<head><style type='text/css'>" + strBuilder.ToString() + "</style></head>");            
Response.Write("<div id='contentTitle'> Entry Planning Report </div><br />");
Response.Write(ReportSelectionHtml + "<br />"); 
Response.End();
```

the above code is working fine in single sheet as you can see i'm injecting my css file text. 
for multiple sheets i'm switching to EPPlus

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with, creating new sheets in EPPlus or splitting the HTML up?

Comment: Thanks for your response. i m facing problem in injecting html in worksheet like ws2.Cells[1, 1].Value = "<table width = '100%' style='color:red;' ><tr ><td >Branch Name:</td><td >data</td></tr></table>";

Comment: Could you post a code snippet to expand upon this? There's a lot of reasons it may not be getting added. The sheet might not be bound to the file, .Save() wasn't called, etc. Are there any exceptions thrown? When you open the file is it just blank or is just one sheet populated? Is it populated with the last set of data or just the first set? Or a bunch of blank sheets?

Comment: i can create multiple sheets in excel via EPPlus with test data.

Answer (score 3):

EPPlus is a great way to create Excel files, but there are some limitations.

As you've noticed, you cannot simply set a cell's value to some HTML code and expect to receive formatted text in the Excel file that is generated. EPPlus supports rich text cell values, but these have to be constructed using method calls to turn on and off the formatting for different portions of your text value. Formats applied to the entire cell are handled separately.

I wrote some utility for converting some *very* basic HTML into EPPlus rich text objects, you'll find it here, it may be of some help:

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/154

That said, based on your comment above, it looks like you're trying to embed an entire *table* within a single Excel cell. This is impossible. If you can't do something in Excel itself, you can't do it in EPPlus. If you want to create a table in Excel, each cell of the worksheet should correspond to a cell in your table. For example:

```
ws2.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Brach Name";
ws2.Cells[1, 2].Value = "data";
```

Setting colors and other styles on a cell is done in a similar manner to setting the value, there are numerous examples in the EPPlus distribution that you can refer to.

Comment: I think he's just trying to save the entire HTML into the Excel sheet which you can do, though it'd be just straight text. Awesome library though, I have a use for that myself.

Comment: yes i'm trying to save entire HTML into the excel sheet. my requirement is to separate my report portion into separate sheets

Comment: Hello @richardtallent the link to your code is not working any more. Is your code still somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @Markus, I've updated the link to a Github issue where I posted the same code.